# Issue running a MySQL DB connection C#

Tags: c#, mysql, database

I'm trying to run a **MySQL** connection to a database. the code is correct, however I'm unable to make the class run.

```
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
        Application.Run(new DBInfo());
    }
}
```

the two errors im getting are"
The best overload method match for `'System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(System.Windows.Forms.Form);` has some invalid arguments

```
Argument '1': cannot convert from 'DBtest.DBInfo' to 'System.Windows.Forms.Form'
```

DBInfo just initialize the application in a seperate script.

```
public DBInfo()
{
    Initialize();
}
```

Comment: are you sure u want to pass that dbinfo to run ?

Comment: Hmm, ive never really used a database in an app before, so im testing it out. Im not really to sure how to approach this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do as below

```
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Application.Run(new Form1());
    //Application.Run(new DBInfo()); remove from here
}
```

you can call `DBInfo` from `Form1`

```
public Form1()
{
    try
    {
        DBInfo db = new  DBInfo();
        // do stuff with DBInfo object like db.GetConnection() etc...
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

[Application.Run](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.run.aspx) method expect Form, ApplicationContext as parameter. your DBInfo method is not return any of them

Comment: Hi, I think that worked, but now the app crashes. lol "DBtest has stopped working"
oh, and I did remove the (Application.Run(new DBInfo())

Comment: You need some exception handling. check the exception that gives you idea what was happened.

Comment: omg.... the results weren't forgiving, you wouldnt happen to know of any tutorials that use MySQL and applications would you?